# TSQL - How to prevent optimisation in this query

Tags: sql-server, optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query analogous to:

```
update x
     set x.y = (
        select sum(x2.y)
        from mytable x2
        where x2.y < x.y
     )
from mytable x
```

the point being, I'm iterating over rows and updating a field based on a subquery over those fields **which are changing**.

What I'm seeing is the subquery is being executed for each row before any updates occur, so the changed values for each row are **not** being picked up.

How can I force the subquery to be re-evaluated for each row of the update?

Is there a suitable table hint or something?

As an aside, I **was** doing the below and it did work, however since modifying my query somewhat (for logic purposes, not to try and solve this issue) this trick no longer works :(

```
declare @temp int
update x
     set @temp = (
        select sum(x2.y)
        from mytable x2
        where x2.y < x.y
     ),
     x.y = @temp
from mytable x
```

I'm not particularly concerned about performance, this is a background task run over a few rows

Comment: I see you posted the one that works, could you also show the one that you are trying to get to work?

Comment: This is not possible. It would be a bug if it was. SQL Server will add appropriate operators to the plan for [Halloween Protection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2008/02/27/halloween-protection.aspx) to prevent the behaviour that you desire.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin what? The top query is what I'm trying to make work. the second one worked previously under different circumstances

Comment: @MartinSmith Interesting, so is there a different way I can write the query to achieve what i want?

Comment: @AndrewBullock - What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: it's not clear how to select next row if you want to do this for each row...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like task is incorrect or other rules should apply.

Let's see on example. Let's say you have values **4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2**

Sql will update rows based on original values. I.e. during single update statement newly calculated values is NOT mixing with original values:

```
--  only original values used
4 -> 9     (1+2+3+1+2)
1 -> null
2 -> 2     (1+1)
3 -> 6     (1+2+1+2)
1 -> null
2 -> 2     (1+1)
```

Based on your request you wants that update of each rows will count newly calculated values. ***(Note, that SQL does not guarantees the sequence in which rows will be processed.)***
Let's do this calculation by processing rows from top to bottom:

```
--  from top
4 -> 9    (1+2+3+1+2)
1 -> null
2 -> 1    (1)
3 -> 4    (1+1+2)
1 -> null
2 -> 1    (1)
```

Do the same in other sequence - from bottom to top:

```
--  from bottom
4 -> 3    (2+1)
1 -> null 
2 -> 1    (1)
3 -> 5    (2+2+1)
1 -> null
2 -> 2    (1+1)
```

How you can see your expected result is inconsistent. To make it right you need to correct the calculation rule - for instance define strong sequence of the rows to process (date, id, ...)
Also, if you want to do some recursive processing look at the **common_table_expression**:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx